# SQL, How to Concatenate results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, concatenation, sql-server-group-concat

I currently have a SQL query that returns a number of fields. I need one f the fields to be effectively a sub query sub that.

**The Problem in detail:**

> If I have a table X with two columns, ModuleID and say ModuleValue, how can I write a SQL query to take the results and Concatenate it into one field:

**EG** Results returned from

```
 (SELECT ModuleValue FROM Table_X WHERE ModuleID=@ModuleID)
```

Value 1

Value 2

Value 3

...

I need to return the result thus (as a single row, unlike the above):

> Value 1, Value 2, Value 3

Is there a simple Concatenation method that could be user?

**EDIT:**

> DB is MS TSQL (2005)

Comment: Are you wanting to just retrieve the data or update another field with it?

Comment: Just Retrieving, Also its MS TSQL

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With MSSQL you can do something like this:

```
declare @result varchar(500)
set @result = ''
select @result = @result + ModuleValue + ', ' 
from TableX where ModuleId = @ModuleId
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go now, will mark you as answered if it works.

Comment: SELECT  LEFT(@result,LEN(@result)-1) AS Txt

Answer (score 39):

This one automatically excludes the trailing comma, unlike most of the other answers.

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @csv = COALESCE(@csv + ',', '') + ModuleValue
FROM Table_X
WHERE ModuleID = @ModuleID
```

*(If the `ModuleValue` column isn't already a string type then you might need to cast it to a `VARCHAR`.)*

Comment: Well noted, in this case it was a varchar, but in other cases this coule well be other value types.

Comment: This is clever and quite elegant.

Answer (score 19):

In mysql you'd use the following function:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ModuleValue, ",") FROM Table_X WHERE ModuleID=@ModuleID
```

I am not sure which dialect you are using.

Comment: Related since it was useful for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Answer (score 16):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT ModuleValue + ','
     FROM dbo.Modules
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ) 
FROM dbo.Modules
WHERE ModuleID = 1
```

This should give you something like what you're looking for.

Marc

Comment: seems interesting, haven't used XML path much. I'll certain play with this one. Thanks!

Comment: how to remove the last delimma, i mean there is still a useless `,` at the end

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, if you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, using `STRING_AGG( ... )` is the best solution:

More at:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42778050/1260488

Comment: This is actually peferct

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the database you are using. MySQL for example supports the (non-standard) [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. So you could write:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ModuleValue) FROM Table_X WHERE ModuleID=@ModuleID
```

Group-concat is not available at all database servers though.

Answer (score 6):

Small update on Marc we will have additional " , "  at the end. i used stuff function to remove extra semicolon .

```
       SELECT STUFF((  SELECT ',' + ModuleValue AS ModuleValue
                           FROM ModuleValue WHERE ModuleID=@ModuleID
                      FOR XML PATH('') 
                     ), 1, 1, '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out with MS SQL Server you can use `CONCAT()` to put things together and then just strip the trailing comma.  Here are a couple of examples using differing techniques.  Note how I used both the `Id` and `Name`
columns with some other characters in one of these to get
`(1)Amir, (2)Sofia, (3)Aya, (4)Mateo, (5)Leila, (6)Yara, (7)Ndidi, (8)Santiag` just as an example.

```
DECLARE @Person as TABLE
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255)
);

DECLARE 
    @AllThingsPerson VARCHAR(500) ='',
    @AllThingsPersonX VARCHAR(500) ='';

INSERT INTO @Person(Id, Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'Amir'),
    (2, 'Sofia'),
    (3, 'Aya'),
    (4, 'Mateo'),
    (5, 'Leila'),
    (6, 'Yara'),
    (7, 'Ndidi'),
    (8, 'Santiago');


SELECT @AllThingsPerson = CONCAT(@AllThingsPerson, Name, ', ') 
FROM @Person;
SELECT SUBSTRING(@AllThingsPerson,0, LEN(@AllThingsPerson)-1);  ;

SELECT @AllThingsPersonX =
(
SELECT CONCAT('(',Id,')',Name, ',') AS 'data()'
FROM @Person
FOR XML PATH('')
);

SELECT SUBSTRING(@AllThingsPersonX,0, LEN(@AllThingsPersonX)-1);
```