# group and concatenate in mysql without using group_concat

Tags: mysql

I need to output all reviews for every product grouped by product id.

```
select product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct text separator '<hr>') as 'Review' from reviews WHERE status = 'A' group by product_id
```

I ‘m using group_concat mysql function which groups and strings together multiples rows into 1.

The maximum number of characters group_concat outputs after running is 1024. Which is not enough since many product reviews exceed 1024 when combined - resulting in incomplete data. I tried to change group_concat_max_len mysql variable to higher number but don't have super previledges.

Is there an alternative method I can use instead of group_concat?

Comment: Why do you need that much data on the client?

Comment: Do you have the privilege for creating user defined functions?

Comment: Why can't you do this application-side?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length