# how to get a single row for each user?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, forum

sorry for the title, i don't know how to explain it better...

i have a forum and i want to make a sort of achievement system in php

i want to know when users with posts>10 posted their 10th message...

the post table is like

```
post_id | post_date | userid | post_message | ...
```

i can get this result for each user with

```
select userid, post_date from posts where userid=1 order by post_date limit 9,1
```

but i need a resultset like

```
id | date
id | date
id | date
```

it can only be done with procedures?

Comment: would you want eash User's 10th post ??

Comment: i thing  r u looking for field heading should be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select 
    * 
from (
    select 
       @rn:=if(@prv=userid, @rn+1, 1) as rid, 
       @prv:=userid as userid,
       post_message
    from 
       tbl
    join 
       (select @rn:=0, @prv:=0) tmp
    order by 
       userid, 
       post_date) tmp 
where 
    rid=10
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/220c2/5)**

```
| RID | USERID | POST_MESSAGE |
-------------------------------
|  10 |      1 |       asdasd |
|  10 |      2 |       asdasd |
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
SELECT userid
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(post_date ORDER BY post_date), ',', 10), ',', -1) AS PostDate
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING PostDate <> '' OR PostDate IS NOT NULL
```

But you need to pay attention with the maximum length that the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length) can hold.

Comment: This would be better than solution with user variables due to reliability, but you need to filter out userids with less than 10 posts, because substring_index will return last one for them. So you need `HAVING count(*) >= 10`.

Comment: Hi @piotrm, I already have `HAVING PostDate <> ''` which eliminates users with less than 10 posts.