# Swapping rows to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I've read previous posts regarding pivot table and swapping rows to columns, but I couldn't find correct answer for my question. I have below table in MySQL:

```
+--------+--------+
| Userid | gname  |
+--------+--------+
|     12 | AVBD   |
|     12 | ASD    |
|     12 | AVFD   |
|     12 | Aew1   |
|     12 | AVBD32 |
|     12 | ASD23  |
|     12 | AVBDe  |
|     12 | ASDer  |
|     45 | AVBD   |
|     45 | ASD444 |
|     45 | AVBD44 |
|     45 | ASD44  |
|    453 | AVBD22 |
|    453 | ASD1   |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to produce an ordered pivot table:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Userid | gname1 | gname2 | gname3 | gname4 | gname5 | gname6 | gname7 | gname8 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     12 | AVBD   | ASD    | AVFD   | Aew1   | AVBD32 | ASD23  | AVBDe  | ASDer  |
|     45 | AVBD   | ASD444 | AVBD44 | ASD44  |        |        |        |        |
|    453 | AVBD22 | ASD1   |        |        |        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

the name of `gname` is dynamic and has no limit.

Here is the data setup along with a SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fec

```
CREATE TABLE gnames
    (`Userid` int, `gname` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO gnames
    (`Userid`, `gname`)
VALUES
    (12, 'AVBD'),
    (12, 'ASD'),
    (12, 'AVFD'),
    (12, 'Aew1'),
    (12, 'AVBD32'),
    (12, 'ASD23'),
    (12, 'AVBDe'),
    (12, 'ASDer'),
    (45, 'AVBD'),
    (45, 'ASD444'),
    (45, 'AVBD44'),
    (45, 'ASD44'),
    (453, 'AVBD22'),
    (453, 'ASD1')
;
```

Comment: In the linked answer,  you would use your column `gname` in place of `order` and your `Userid` in place of `ID`.

Comment: how about 'data' column??

Comment: Sorry - it looks like you would use `gname` in place of `data`, `Userid` in place of `ID`, and just omit `order`. I'll try to setup a similar example on sqlfiddle...

Comment: tnx, then can you plz unmark my question??

Comment: I just unmarked it because I was not successful in converting the other answer.  I'm also tagging it with [pivot] which will put it back onto the front page.

Comment: in fact, i tried that answer before posting it;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be significantly easier if MySQL supported windowing functions because it's not necessarily the easiest to create a row number for each `userid`.  I'll show you two ways to do this with hard-coded queries (limited number of results) and then I'll include one version that is using dynamic SQL.

In order to get the final result, you need some sequential number for each `gname` within the `userid`.  This can be done a few different ways.

First, you can use a correlated subquery to `count` the number of `gname`s per user, you'd then use this sequence to create your new columns via an aggregate function with `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  userid,
  max(case when gnameNum = 1 then gname else '' end) gname1,
  max(case when gnameNum = 2 then gname else '' end) gname2,
  max(case when gnameNum = 3 then gname else '' end) gname3,
  max(case when gnameNum = 4 then gname else '' end) gname4,
  max(case when gnameNum = 5 then gname else '' end) gname5,
  max(case when gnameNum = 6 then gname else '' end) gname6,
  max(case when gnameNum = 7 then gname else '' end) gname7,
  max(case when gnameNum = 8 then gname else '' end) gname8
from 
(
  select userid, 
    gname,
    (select count(*)
     from gnames d
     where g.userid = d.userid
       and g.gname <= d.gname) as gnameNum
  from gnames g
) src
group by userid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fec/16/0). Inside the subquery you are creating a row number for each `gname`, you then use this new value in the column creation.  The problem with correlated subqueries is you could suffer from performance issues on larger data sets.

A second method would be to include user variables to create the row number.  This code uses 2 variables to compare the previous row to the current row and increases the row number, if the `userid` is the same as the previous row. Again, you'd use the row number created to convert the data to new columns:

```
select 
  userid,
  max(case when rownum = 1 then gname else '' end) gname1,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then gname else '' end) gname2,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then gname else '' end) gname3,
  max(case when rownum = 4 then gname else '' end) gname4,
  max(case when rownum = 5 then gname else '' end) gname5,
  max(case when rownum = 6 then gname else '' end) gname6,
  max(case when rownum = 7 then gname else '' end) gname7,
  max(case when rownum = 8 then gname else '' end) gname8
from 
(
  select 
    g.userid,
    g.gname,
    @row:=case when @prev=userid then @row else 0 end + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=userid
  from gnames g
  cross join 
  (
    select @row:=0, @prev:=null
  ) r
  order by userid, gname
) src
group by userid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fec/17/0).

Now, in order to do this dynamically you will need to use a [prepared statement](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html). This process will create a sql string that you'll execute to get the final result.  For this example, I used the user variable query above:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when rownum = ',
      rownum,
      ' then gname else '''' end) AS `gname',
      rownum, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from
(
  select 
    g.userid,
    g.gname,
    @row:=case when @prev=userid then @row else 0 end + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=userid
  from gnames g
  cross join 
  (
    select @row:=0, @prev:=null
  ) r
  order by userid, gname
) src;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT userid, ', @sql, ' 
                  from
                  (
                    select 
                      g.userid,
                      g.gname,
                      @row:=case when @prev=userid then @row else 0 end + 1 as rownum,
                      @prev:=userid
                    from gnames g
                    cross join 
                    (
                      select @row:=0, @prev:=null
                    ) r
                    order by userid, gname
                  ) src
                  group by userid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fec/15).  All three versions will give a result of:

```
| USERID | GNAME1 | GNAME2 | GNAME3 | GNAME4 | GNAME5 | GNAME6 | GNAME7 | GNAME8 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|     12 |   Aew1 |    ASD |  ASD23 |  ASDer |   AVBD | AVBD32 |  AVBDe |   AVFD |
|     45 |  ASD44 | ASD444 |   AVBD | AVBD44 |        |        |        |        |
|    453 |   ASD1 | AVBD22 |        |        |        |        |        |        |
```

One thing to consider when using the dynamic SQL is MySQL has a set length for the `group_concat_max_len`, if you have a lot of columns being created you might run into issues. You'll want to account for that.  Here is another question that deals with this [MySQL and GROUP_CONCAT() maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length).

Comment: thanks so much, i've tried the last section of code to a sample of my real data in fiddle, it works like a charm, but when I run it in my workbench I've got an error in "prepare stmt from @sql" line Error:1064, do you have any idea why??

Comment: @MT467 Unfortunately, I'm not at all familiar with that. I can't help you resolve that issue.

Comment: BTW, there is one row that is cut by group_concat(), does it affect the result?

Comment: @MT467 That's what my last statement in the answer covers - you'll need to look at the `group_concat_max_len` length and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Yep! exactly thats the point, increased it and the warning went away:)