# In SQL, is there a way to turn a table into a list?

Tags: mysql

I have tables that look like this:

```
mysql> select id, name from wp_bp_groups limit 5;
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | name                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  3 | Some Group Here                         |
| 11 | Another Group Here                      |
| 29 | Groupy Groupy Groupy Group              |
| 39 | Some Other Other Group Goes Here        |
|  7 | Yep, Here's a Test Group                |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select group_id, user_id from wp_bp_groups_members limit 5;
+----------+---------+
| group_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|       17 |      71 |
|       24 |     209 |
|       22 |     175 |
|       17 |     200 |
|       17 |     102 |
+----------+---------+
```

Eventually, I want to get an array that lists all the members in a group, so I have a SQL query that joins them, like this:

```
SELECT wp_bp_groups.name, wp_bp_groups_members.user_id FROM wp_bp_groups LEFT JOIN wp_bp_groups_members ON wp_bp_groups.id = wp_bp_groups_members.group_id;
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT wp_bp_groups.name, wp_bp_groups_members.user_id from wp_bp_groups left join wp_bp_groups_members on wp_bp_groups.id = wp_bp_groups_members.group_id limit 5;
+------------------+---------+
| name             | user_id |
+------------------+---------+
| Test Group       |       1 |
| Test Group       |     206 |
| Test Group       |      24 |
| Test Group       |      47 |
| Test Group       |      52 |
+------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

But I'd ideally like it to return something more like this:

```
name: Test Group
user_ids: 1, 206, 24, 47, 52
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `select GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) from ... group by name`

Comment: @MateuszNowak - why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: be careful with `GROUP_CONCAT` because it has a maximum length that's not so big http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can use function `group_concat` which will make concatenation of all elements in each group. So you have to group your results. As you want to get all users ids you can query

```
SELECT wp_bp_groups.name, GROUP_CONCAT(wp_bp_groups_members.user_id) as user_ids FROM wp_bp_groups LEFT JOIN wp_bp_groups_members ON wp_bp_groups.id = wp_bp_groups_members.group_id group by wp_bp_groups.name;
```

which should results as

```
+------------------+----------------------+
| name             | user_ids             |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Test Group       |       1,206,24,47,52 |
+------------------+----------------------+
```