# GROUP_CONCAT() mysql returns limited characters

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have to two tables

tblColorLibrary

```
id   name
1     test color
```

tblColors

```
id  libraryId  colorCode  name
1     1           #fff     Prime Color
2     1           #ddd     Secondry Color
3     1           #E2CFC7  Favorite Color
```

Below is my query:

```
$stmt ="SELECT a.id, a.isActive as isActive, a.name as title, GROUP_CONCAT(b.colorCode ) as colors, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) as name FROM ".$this->tblLibrary." as a JOIN tblcolors as b ON a.id = b.libraryId GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY b.id ASC";
```

This query will return result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [isActive] => Y
            [title] => test
            [colors] => #fff,#ddd,#E2CFC7
            [name] => Prime Color, Secondry Color, Favorite Color
        )

)
```

All goes fine till I have limited records. When I have above 150 records in tblColors, name key gives only limited number of characters. Not getting full records.

I guess there will be limitation in group concat.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` has a max length of about 1024. You can change this through server variables. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Comment: Check `group_concat_max_len`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: @pala_ yes you are right i checked strlen($name), it says 1024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase your group_concat_max_len at mysql database. by default it set to 1024. you can update it by using query

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=100000
```

and

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Comment: After adding your answer it is working on my local server and not in live server, hope we will not have privilege to set this on live server, any idea about this?

Comment: run this query $sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;" before your mysql query

Comment: Yes I set so, and it started working on local wamp, but when I moved this to production server it is not working :-(

Comment: I came to know that since it is shared server I can do this any other idea to modify the length other than this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of group_concat_max_len and increase it as needed.

```
show variables like 'group_concat_max_len';
```