# How to set group_concat_max_len with MySQL and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

> while using group concat in query I am not able to get all the event
>   group name due to default length of group concat is 1024 so how I can
>   set max_length of group concat in existing code.

I have a code here were I am using group concat and set max len

```
==========================================================================
        DATA_QUERY="set group_concat_max_len=10024;
 select group_concat(eg.name) from event_groups eg left join theatres t ON t.theatre_id = eg.theatre_id group by t.theatre_id order by t.application_name"

        Session session = getFacadeLookup().getPersistenceFacade().getHibernateSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(DATA_QUERY) and execute 

        List<Object[]> lstResult = query.list();
============================================================================
```

error set group_concat_max_len not support here

Comment: I don't think you can set the session-attributes that way. What not split the result in more than one query to get around the limit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Comment: i am using hibernate session object for creating sqlQuery so how i can set **SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the `group_concat_max_len` first:

```
session.doWork(connection -> {
    try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.execute("SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=10024");
    }
});
```

or pre-Java 8 syntax:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute("SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=10024");
        }
    }
});
```

And only then execute your query:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select group_concat(eg.name) " +
    "from event_groups eg " +
    "left join theatres t ON t.theatre_id = eg.theatre_id " +
    "group by t.theatre_id order by t.application_name");
List<Object[]> lstResult = query.list();
```

Comment: is it possible in jre 1.7 version session.doWork(connection -> lamda sign not supported by jre 1.7 version

Comment: Yes of course. You need to use the `new Work () {}` anonymous class syntax then.

Comment: session.doWork(new Work() { 
   @Override
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException 
 {
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) 
       {
statement .execute("SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=10024");
statement.close();
} }});
it works fine thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use Hikari connection pool, you can set all session configuration values when the session is started in the in `connection-init-sql` like below,

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=SET sql_require_primary_key = off;SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```