# How to use MySQL group_concat() function in more than one column

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have this query

```
SELECT de.id as id_evento,de.evento, dp.id as id_participante,
        dp.nombre as participante,pn.participacion,
        pn.id as id_participacion
                FROM difusion_evento de,difusion_evento_participante dep,difusion_participante dp,
                      difusion_participacion pn
                WHERE de.id=dep.difusion_evento_id
                  AND dep.difusion_participante_id=dp.id
                  AND dep.difusion_participacion_id=pn.id
                  AND de.id=5
                  ORDER BY 3,6
```

And the results are:

```
id_evento    evento  id_participante     participante    participacion   id_participacion
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  8    Name1   participante   2
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  8    Name1   comentarista   4
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  9    Name2   participante   2
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  10   Name3   participante   2
```

But i want the results to appear like the following:

```
id_evento    evento  id_participante     participante    participacion   id_participacion
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  8    Name1   participante,comentarista  2, 4
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  9    Name2   participante   2
5    5TO SEMINARIO PERMANENTE…  10   Name3   participante   2
```

That is to say, i want the id_participante column to appear DISTINCT and the two columns `participacion`and `id_participacion` to be grouped. For example, Name1 appears two times and i want to group its results in one column.

I have tried GROUP_CONCAT() wth no luck, any ideas to achieve this?

**Solved**
Thanks to the first answer, i was missing, indeed, the GROUP BY id_participante

So the working query is:

```
SELECT de.id as id_evento,de.evento, dp.id as id_participante,
    dp.nombre as participante,GROUP_CONCAT(pn.participacion SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(pn.id SEPARATOR ', ') as id_participacion
            FROM difusion_evento de,difusion_evento_participante dep,difusion_participante dp,
                  difusion_participacion pn
            WHERE de.id=dep.difusion_evento_id
              AND dep.difusion_participante_id=dp.id
              AND dep.difusion_participacion_id=pn.id
              AND de.id=5
            GROUP BY id_participante
            ORDER BY 3,6
```

Comment: what's the matter with `select group_concat(participacion), group_concat(id_participacion)`? as long as your `group by` clause is set correct, there's no reason that shouldn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length?rq=1

Comment: @MarcB I get the `can't group on id_participacion` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY id_participante` to group by `id_participante`.

You will have distinct participant ids on separate lines, and the other fields are grouped together per participant id.

```
SELECT de.id as id_evento,de.evento, dp.id as id_participante,
    dp.nombre as participante,pn.participacion,
    pn.id as id_participacion
            FROM difusion_evento de,difusion_evento_participante dep,difusion_participante dp,
                  difusion_participacion pn
            WHERE de.id=dep.difusion_evento_id
              AND dep.difusion_participante_id=dp.id
              AND dep.difusion_participacion_id=pn.id
              AND de.id=5
            GROUP BY id_participante
            ORDER BY 3,6
```