# How to avoid automatic truncation of GROUP_CONCAT result

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve a long set of result and in doing so I find that the result data is being truncated automatically. I also noticed that the limit of result(String) is 1024 characters. How can I avoid this to get whole data?

I am accessing tables through JDBC, if that matters.

Code:-

```
SELECT OLL.EMAIL_ID,COUNT(1) AS TOTAL_ORDERS,OLL.SHIPPING_NAME ,SUM(OFF.UNIT_PRICE*OFF.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_GMV,
MIN(ODD.CREATION_DATE) AS FIRST_PURCHASE,MAX(ODD.CREATION_DATE) AS LAST_PURCHASE,GROUP_CONCAT(OFF.PAYMENT_MODE) AS PAY_MODES, 
GROUP_CONCAT(OFLL.PRODUCT_ID)AS PRODUCT_IDS,LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(OFLL.PRODUCT_NAME),2048) AS PRODUCTS,OLL.BRAND_NAME,GROUP_CONCAT(OFF.GCTYPE) AS GCTYPE,
OLL.SHIPPING_CITY,OLL.SHIPPING_STATE,GROUP_CONCAT(OFF.UNIT_PRICE-OFF.UNIT_SHIPPING_PRICE) AS PRODUCT_PRICE,GROUP_CONCAT(CEILING(OFF.QUANTITY*OFF.UNIT_PRICE)) AS PRODUCT_GMV,GROUP_CONCAT(OFLL.CHANNEL) AS SALES_CHANNEL 
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(1), OL.ORDER_ID, OL.EMAIL_ID, OFL.CREATED_BY,OL.SELLER_CITY,OL.SHIPPING_STATE 
FROM (SELECT CREATION_DATE,ORDER_ID,ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID FROM ORDER_DATES WHERE CREATION_DATE  
BETWEEN '2015-01-30 23:55:00' AND '2015-01-30 23:59:59') OD 
INNER JOIN ORDER_LOGISTICS OL ON OD.ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID AND OD.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID = OL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID 
INNER JOIN ORDER_FINANCE OF ON OL.ORDER_ID = OF.ORDER_ID AND OL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID = OF.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID 
INNER JOIN ORDER_FILTERS OFL ON OL.ORDER_ID = OFL.ORDER_ID AND OL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID = OFL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID 
INNER JOIN ORDER_STATUS OS ON OL.ORDER_ID = OS.ORDER_ID AND OL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID = OS.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID 
WHERE (OF.PAYMENT_MODE='Cash On Delivery' OR OS.PAYMENT_STATUS='Received')AND (OFL.PRODUCT_ID IN ('B4333897','B5163012','B5654542') OR OF.UNIT_PRICE-OF.UNIT_SHIPPING_PRICE='1.00') AND 
OFL.CHANNEL IN ('Web Channel', 'Mobile Web Channel') AND 
OL.EMAIL_ID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY OL.EMAIL_ID) AAA, ORDER_LOGISTICS OLL, ORDER_FILTERS OFLL, 
ORDER_FINANCE OFF,ORDER_DATES ODD WHERE AAA.EMAIL_ID=OLL.EMAIL_ID AND 
OLL.ORDER_ID=OFLL.ORDER_ID AND OLL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID=OFLL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID AND (OFLL.PRODUCT_ID IN ('B4333897','B5163012','B5654542') OR OFF.UNIT_PRICE-OFF.UNIT_SHIPPING_PRICE='1.00') AND
OFLL.ORDER_ID=ODD.ORDER_ID AND OFF.ORDER_ID=OLL.ORDER_ID AND OFF.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID=OLL.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID 
GROUP BY OLL.EMAIL_ID
```

Since I am using GROUP_CONCAT(), the result comes out to be lengthy and that's where it gets truncated.

Comment: Java and MySQL, does that mean JDBC and MySQL Connector/J?

Comment: Yes, I am using JDBC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL and GROUP\_CONCAT() maximum length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length)