# MYSQL List all products with all categories

Tags: mysql

I have this schema:

**table_products**: product_id, name, price,

**table_categories**: category_id, name,

**table_categories_products**: category_id, product_id

I want list all products from my db  including all the categories of each product.

Actually i use this query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_id, ';', c.name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table_products
LEFT JOIN table_categories_products tcp ON tcp.product_id=p.product_id
LEFT JOIN table_categories c ON c.category_id=p.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

The problem is that one product could be inside unlimited categories and the group_concat has a size limit.

**Update**

I had already considered the option of increase "group_concat_max_len", but dont't allow for an infinite string

Comment: You can increase the limit of `GROUP_CONCAT` for you current session, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length).  But if you expect an infinite string then you should change your query.

Answer (score 2):

You can change group_concat max size by :

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

default is 1024, and maximal settable value is 1073741824

at least that is what doc says:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I had already considered that option, but dont't allow for an infinite string

Comment: That's true, but in given case, if we have so big number of categories that we can't write them in one line of text then we can suspect that those data are bad.
Other approach is to select all relation and concat them out of SQL.