# Improve SQL Query performance in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the query, I use to count the total number of rows (I need this for pagination)

```
$sql = "SELECT count(tmdb_id),group_concat(genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

 FROM `tmdb_movies` 

JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres1' )
    AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres2' )

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.tmdb_id";


$result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$totalrows = $result->rowCount();
```

Screenshot of this query with `EXPLAIN` statement

[image]

This is the SQL query, I use to echo results

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

FROM tmdb_movies

LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres1' )
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres2' )

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start"); 

     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();

     // Pick up the result as an array
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();




    // Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
     for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){
   echo $result[$x]["movie_title"];

}
```

Screenshot of `EXPLAIN` statement with this query

[image]

Here, the first query takes around `0.6` seconds to execute, and second one also takes around `0.6` seconds to execute.

Is there any way to merge both the SQL Query's to save execution time?

Any other way to increase SQL Query performance?

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://rextester.com/XIHD98729) of second SQL Query.

**My Indexes:**

```
create index idxm on tmdb_movies(tmdb_id);
create index idxv on videos(videos_tmdb_id, videos_name, videos_key);
create index idxv on genres(genres_name, tmdb_id );
```

Comment: You do know there is a character limit on GROUP_CONCAT, right.  Text past this limit will be truncated...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in MySQL for which CONCAT or GROUP_CONCAT need form any part of the answer. This is doubly true for result sets which are subsequently parsed in PHP, and, typically, performance is improved by their removal. So I'd start there.

Comment: Also, correlated subqueries tend to perform more slowly than uncorrelated ones

Comment: Oh and also see SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats the point of this

I wouldn't say this is an answer, because query optimization, is never that easy, this is more query simplification ...

```
WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres1' )
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres2' )
```

Isn't this equivalent  ( it's all ands )

```
WHERE
EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name IN( '$genres1','$genres2'))
```

My guess is the sorting is gonna kill you...  To try run it without the sort.

If that is quick then sometimes sorting in an inner query that pulls just ID's can help, because sort might make a temp table, so pulling the smallest amount of information sorting it, then doing an outer query with a join, can help.

Something like this ( note I cant really test this so it's just a guess, although I have had success using this method in the past )

```
SELECT
    tmdb_movies1.movie_title
    ,tmdb_movies1.tmdb_id
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
    FROM
        tmdb_movies
    WHERE
        EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name IN('$genres1','$genres2' ))
    GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
    ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start
) AS tmdb_movies0
JOIN
    tmdb_movies AS tmdb_movies1 
ON
    tmdb_movies0.tmdb_id = tmdb_movies1.tmdb_id
LEFT JOIN
    videos
ON
    videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies1.tmdb_id
JOIN
    genres ON genres.tmdb_id = tmdb_movies1.tmdb_id
```

Basically to speed up the sorting, your pulling out the smallest amount of data, just an ID, sorting them and then using that to Join and pull out the rest of the data ( the bulk ) that lets you create the smallest Temp table possible with the sort, which uses less memory etc...

It could work.... ( 15% chance really ... ha ha )

*** As a side note ***
Or's can also be a killer, ( although I don't see any ) you can get some performance from a query with `or` by doing a similar trick with a sub query that uses UNION, instead of OR, and pulls just the Pk ID's.  Then joins back on the tables to pull out the data, 2 Unions queries can be equivalent to an OR.

**NOTE**
   I would not be doing you a good service If i didn't mention SQL Injection,  So use prepared statements for this stuff `'.$var.'`

Comment: It gives me some error, check this fiddle http://rextester.com/HQJRH16867

Comment: LOL, you messed the `S` in `ELECT` as in `SELECT`  Fixing that you'll get this `SELECT command denied to user 'rextester_user'@'localhost' for table 'tmdb_id'`

Comment: Oh yes, the same error, i am getting in my PHP file. What's the fix of that new error bro? And thanks a lot

Comment: Remove the field from the table name in the `JOIN tmdb_movies.tmdb_id AS tmdb_movies1`  Should be `JOIN tmdb_movies AS tmdb_movies1`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'KC_movies.tmdb_movies.popularity' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Oh god, i get this error all the time.

Comment: this is what I get
`1 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL`

Comment: You may have to use `genres.genres_name IN( 'Crime','Drama' )`
http://rextester.com/DHSBZ93643

Comment: `genres.genres_name IN( 'Crime','Drama' )` this gives me this error: `Unknown column 'genres.genres_name' in 'where clause'`

And it is not supposed to give `NULL` right? Because Logan movie have Crime+Drama genres.

Comment: DEPENDS if that should be OR, using IN is like using an OR

Comment: `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` :/

Comment: That stinks!  I don't think there is much I can do about that.

Comment: This post has some info in it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by  You could try setting it at run time.  `SET sql_mode = ''`  Just to see if the query is faster then the other way.

Comment: I've used tricks like this on a table with over 100Million rows.  Just thought I mention that ( we just changed to MongoDB for that table )

Comment: Oh and here is the result from the last fiddle `1|Logan|1|rgret34,rfrf34|Official|Trailer,Trailer|2|Crime,Comedy,Drama`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Internet stopped working. Last fiddle is giving this result `1 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL` http://rextester.com/MJIMW41225

Comment: Sorry, I must not have saved it after changing it to in try this one http://rextester.com/CZTBW36219

Comment: I should mention this `IN ('Crime','Drama' )` is like doing an OR, so you may have to do both exists queries.  As AND and one is not working because it does the AND on the same row, which is impossible.

Comment: for that you can use this one http://rextester.com/UDCOR66233 they produce the same result in this case, but they are not the same logic.

Comment: Last thing is this ( fiddle ) was missing the sort part, which is probably what the issue was to begin with, so without that it's difficult to say if this is faster.   `ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start`  Should go right after `GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id` in the sub-query

Comment: Allowing an end user to sort on `$sortby` ( besides the sql injection possibility ) allows them to sort on non-indexed fields such as `movie_title`  which will DESTROY any performance from this query ( your original ).  Even my updated one will suffer for it.  This is probably 75% chance your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try filter while doing join with genres table.

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

    FROM tmdb_movies
    LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
    left JOIN genres  ON genres.tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id and genres.genres_name = '$genres1' AND genres.genres_name = '$genres2')
    --WHERE 1=1
    --AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres1' )
    --AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM genres  WHERE tmdb_movies.tmdb_id = genres.tmdb_id AND genres.genres_name = '$genres2' )
    GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
    ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT 10 OFFSET $start
```

**you can skip records while joining, this will help to improve your query performance.**

```
   left JOIN genres  ON genres.tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id and genres.genres_name = '$genres1' AND genres.genres_name = '$genres2')
```

Try above code and check.