# Create MySQL view with variables

Tags: mysql, view

I want to create a view out of values from different tables. After 2 day of researching without a result I'm now asking for some hints.

This is the table **op_id** which stores only operationID's

```
|  op_id  |
|---------|
| 20180101|
| 20180102|
|      ...|
```

For each op_id in op_id - table exists a own table. For example **operations_20180101**, **operations_20180102**, ...

The content of each table looks

```
| username | data |
|----------|------|
|  john    |  1239|
|  adam    |   857|
|       ...|   ...|
```

What I try to do is, create a view with the sum(data) of all single tables:

```
| 20180101 |  3746|
| 20180102 |  4765|
|       ...|   ...|
```

To create a simple SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM operationview
```

to get all the data I need.

With

```
SELECT op_id FROM op_id
```

I get all my op_id's.

But from there I don't know how to store the result in a variable and query the corresponding table to create a view like

```
for op_id in (SELECT op_id FROM op_id):
    CREATE VIEW overview (SELECT op_id, sum(data) FROM operations_op_id)
```

All I got from MySQL Documentation looks simple, but doesn't solve my problem. It's the first time I try to do more complex stuff than querying and subquerying. So please excuse my question if the solution is simpler then I can figure out.

Comment: You have many operations_ tables (1 a day)? And the only technology you have is mysql?

Comment: Yes, one table a day. This is a Django Website. So, if Python can help I can use it. My thoughts about using Python is, that the query might be very slow and it takes too much time to render the webpage.

That's why I want to let the database do the stuff.

Comment: Once the data is populated for a day, does it's going to change later?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Maybe some calculation of data arrive several days later, but put in their corresponding table.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly looking for dynamic sql where you build code to be executed. For example given

```
drop table if exists op_id,operations_20180101 ,operations_20180102  ;

create table op_id (op_id  int);
insert into op_id values
(20180101),
(20180102);

create table operations_20180101(username varchar(3) ,data int);
create table operations_20180102(username varchar(3) ,data int);

insert into operations_20180101 values 
('aaa',1),('bbb',2);

insert into operations_20180102 values 
('aaa',10),('bbb',20);
```

You can build a sql statement like this

```
set @sql = 
(select
replace 
(
(select 
 group_concat(concat('select ', op_id, ',sum(data) as sumdata from ',
 concat('operations_',op_id) ,
 ' union ')
 )
from
(select distinct op_id from op_id) s
) 
,'union ,','union '
)
)
;
set @sql = concat(Substring(@sql,1,length(@sql) -7),';');
```

Which unions all the defined tables and look like this

```
select 20180101,sum(data) as sumdata from operations_20180101 
union 
select 20180102,sum(data) as sumdata from operations_20180102;
```

which can then be passed to sql to execute like this

```
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

result

```
+----------+---------+
| 20180101 | sumdata |
+----------+---------+
| 20180101 |       3 |
| 20180102 |      30 |
+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thnks, this brings a little light into my confusion. But if I copy your code, I get the following error:

MariaDB [registry]> prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: I ran this in mariadb without error did you run the entire code segment from set @sql =

Comment: You may run into the group_concat limit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Comment: I thought about a config problem, but then I installed MariaDB on a fresh Arch. Then copy and past your code. Still have the same error. Same on a MySQL installation. Error occurs at 'execute sqlstmt;'. Is there a different syntax between MariaDB versions? I installed 10.1.32.