# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with inner CONCAT cutting out values? inconsequent results

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I've been trying to set up a rather large query which has a select which should return a group_concat(inated) column which should contain exactly 4 concat(inated) results which are a result of a larger query.

I'll show the select to clear up any confusion (hopefully):

```
# Group the local category_feature_product.id, local feature value -
# and external feature value for the product together.
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(cfpt.category_feature_product_id, '||', pcfpt.category_feature_product_id, '||', cfpt.value, '||', pcfpt.value)
    SEPARATOR ';'
) AS mysql_category_feature_products
```

I expect the query above to always return 4 results, may there be nulls in it or not, but it sometimes just only returns 3 or 2 results per group_concat. (i.e.: `273458||2658774||5` gets returned).

How can I assure that there is at least ALWAYS a null returned?
I could show the large query if needed.

-- UPDATE --

Hereby the full query, a valid data example, actual result and the expected result as requested.

Full query:

I'm going to filter the results down to one product, since there are tens of thousands results. I will also only use the `mysql_category_feature_products` column.

Actual result (Notice the last row):

Expected result (notice last row) & valid data example:

-- UPDATED (AGAIN) --

The actual expected reuslt for the last row is not `250258||2583482||null||6` BUT `250258||2583482||47||67` not null, my bad.

Rerunning the query with the new ifnull statement returns a different oucome for the last row: `250258||2583482||4` instead of `250258||2583482||6`

Comment: seems strange  .. please  .. updated  you question add  a valid data sample, your actual result and the expected  result  ..  (and also the complete query code)

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

you could check for null  (in this case  i add  a `-` char but you can use a '')

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(ifnull(cfpt.category_feature_product_id, '-')
    , '||'
    , ifnull(pcfpt.category_feature_product_id, '-')
    , '||'
    , ifnull(cfpt.value,'-')
    , '||'
    , ifnull(pcfpt.value,'-')
    SEPARATOR ';'
) AS mysql_category_feature_products
```

Comment: So I was a bit too quick in the actual data example as null shouldn't be possible anymore. (See the new update for the actual expected result).

Comment: Is there a length limit to the GROUP_CONCAT method? It seems like the result gets cut off..

Comment: Yes  .. there is a GROUP_CONCAT limit  ..  and you can change .. anyway  .. the  problem related  to  missing columns in solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

So the results got broken because of the default 1024 character limit set by MySQL on default, this can be circumvented by changing the length for your current session. see [MySQL and GROUP_CONCAT() maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length)