# group_concat string getting truncated

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables as follows:

```
class Workflows():
    __tablename__ = 'workflows'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255),unique=True)

class Tasks():   
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    workflow_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('workflows.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), server_default=u'')
    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(),default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

I have written a simple query using sqlalchemy ORM which is follows:

```
(
    db.session.query(
        Workflows.id,
        (
            '[' +
            func.group_concat(
                '{"name": "', Tasks.name, '", "modified_date": "', Tasks.modified_at, '"}'
            )
            + ']'
        ).label('task_name')
    )
    .filter(Workflows.id == Tasks.workflow_id)
    .group_by(Workflows.id)
    .all()
)
```

When I execute above query I get the expected output which is a pair of `Workflows.id` and `group_concat(dict)`. An example of output is:

```
[
    {'id': 30, 'task_name': '[{'name': 'Task 1', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 12:59:51'}, {'name': 'Task 2', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 12:59:51'}, {'name': 'Task 3', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 12:59:51'}]'},
    {'id': 31, 'task_name': '[{'name': 'Task A', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 13:01:58'}, {'name': 'Task B', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 13:01:58'}, {'name': 'Task C', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 13:01:58'}]'}
]
```

The problem occurs when I use the above query as a subquery. When I change the above query and use it is an alias in another query the `task_name` gets truncated. For example if I run following query:

```
workflow_data = (
    db.session.query(
        Workflows.id,
        (
            '[' +
        func.group_concat(
            '{"name": "', Tasks.name, '", "modified_date": "', Tasks.modified_at, '"}'
            )
            + ']'
        ).label('task_name')
    )
    .filter(Workflows.id == Tasks.workflow_id)
    .group_by(Workflows.id)
    .subquery()
)

sub_data = (
    db.session.query(
        workflow_data
    )
    .all()
)
```

Here when I print `sub_data`, I get following output:

```
[
    {'id': 30, 'task_name': '[{'name': 'Task 1', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 12:59:51'}, {'name': 'Tas
    {'id': 31, 'task_name': '[{'name': 'Task A', 'modified_date': '2019-03-07 13:01:58'}, {'name': 'Tas
]
```

`task_name` in output is getting truncated over a particular length. I believe I need to increase GROUP_CONCAT length limit like this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length) post. But I can't figure out how to do it in sqlalchemy. If there is any other solution than that will also do.

Comment: I can't simply execute raw SQL as there are much more queries that needs to be executed on the subquery object.

Comment: *"I can't simply execute raw SQL as there are much more queries that needs to be executed on the subquery object."* Only way possible you need to do it before using the `GROUP_CONCAT()` or you need to configure it on the server and reboot it..

Comment: What @raymond is getting at (I think) is that you will have to execute the `SET` statement in your session *before* using it to issue your query that's using `group_concat()`.