# Change MySQL “group_concat_max_len” value in cpanel / whm

Tags: mysql

I need to increase `group_concat_max_len` value on my server but I don't know how to use ssh command.

Is there a way to change this value in GUI of cpanel / whm? I have access to both cpanel and whm.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len you can change this setting in your current session so you can use the `SET` command. Have you tried using the `SET` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length

Comment: I don't know how to use SSH command, is there way to do this with GUI?