# most efficient way of making html options list from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I can retrieve records from my **tables** above **5000 record** minimal, and I have four ways to do it, and I don't know which and why is the suitable for my requested work and which is best if it was lesser records: [(Queries)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/504b20/9)

```
#---- Rows
SELECT
  a.`id`,
  a.`content`
FROM
  `docs` a;
```

I use **while() loop** for each row:

```
while ($row = $rows->fetch()) {
  echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['content']}</option>";
}
```

---

```
#---- Group
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    a.`id`,
    ".",
    a.`content`
  ) AS `options`
FROM
  `docs` a;
```

I use **explode() + foreach() loop** *(content isn't allowed naturally to have "." in its text)*:

```
foreach (explode(",", $options) as $option) {
  $option = explode(".", $option); //[0]: id, [1]: content
  echo "<option value=\"{$option[0]}\">{$option[1]}</option>";
}
```

---

```
#---- HTML Rows
SELECT
  CONCAT("<option value=\"",a.`id`,"\">",a.`content`,"</option>") AS `option`
FROM
  `docs` a;
```

I apply **html in query** and then use **while() loop**:

```
while ($row = $rows->fetch()) {
  echo $row;
}
```

---

```
#---- HTML Group
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT("<option value=\"",a.`id`,"\">",a.`content`,"</option>" SEPARATOR "")
FROM
  `docs` a;
```

here everything is already made in query to just print:

```
echo $rows->fetch();
```

Comment: 5000 isn't a lot of records for a query, but it's far too many to put into a `<select>` - it will be unusable. Consider the user experience if you have to scroll through such a large list. What user interface are you actually trying to build?

Comment: @ADyson I did try to convince my client that it can be done a lot better with `client-side` and `search functionality`, but it was insisted to make it into a `<select>` for reasons I am not allowed to know, but it was very emphasized that it is needed to be the most efficient and performant both on server and client.

Comment: `was insisted to make it into a <select>`.... `it is needed to be the most efficient and performant`...these two things are contradictory, when there are 5000 or more records. You need to explain this to the client. Maybe show them a demo with just 100 records in the select - even then, anyone can see it's not usable. You're right, some sort of auto-complete search function would make a lot more sense. Or a paginated list to browse through.

Comment: @ADyson tried to explain and prove a lot, but it was in the end "just need this back-end work, the front-end will be managed with other specialized developer in it" response (I believe his work won't have more than 200 ~ 500 records and he exaggerated in the data sample he gave me to work on).

Comment: But right now your code is generating the front-end UI (i.e. the HTML code). If they want another developer to build the UI then maybe your code should be returning machine-readable format like JSON, which front-end developer can the turn into whatever user experience they wish.

Comment: @ADyson thought and discussed the same, but in the end I had to ask this question, since what is request doesn't seem to be changeable, the 5000 records can be omitted in the end and seen as 20 ~ 50 records.

Comment: So what exactly is your question then really? Are you asking which of these methods is fastest? To find that out you just have to test it with a large sample. But the simplest query is likely to be faster I'd say. The GROUP_CONCAT stuff doesn't seem to add anything useful and probabably just adds overhead and complication. (Having said all that, again 5000 is not a lot of records for a database or PHP to process, it's barely worth worrying about. The user experience is the tricky part.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take your customer's requirement at face value, even though a 5000-element dropdown menu would drive me bonkers if I had to use it.

You might consider using the [HTML5 datalist element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) to improve this UX a bit.

From php's point of view, the way you generate this code probably doesn't matter enough to worry about.  From MySQL's point of view, however, the simpler query with the `while` loop -- your first choice -- is better. Why?

- GROUP_CONCAT() needs a setting if you generate long strings with it. Read this. [MySQL and GROUP_CONCAT() maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length)   A wise developer, especially when faced with a strange requirement, keeps it simple.
- Processing a medium-sized result set row by row can reduce RAM requirements in your php program, and in your MySQL server.
- It's easier to read for the inevitable time when you, or somebody, needs to do a better job of this user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery select2 and apply search method on it, which will fetch data via AJAX call. I use JSON to populate the select. I am adding sample code here, modify as per your requirement.

Sample HTML

```
                <select name="ItemID" id="ItemID">
                    <option value="0">--</option>
                </select>
```

Related javascript

```
        $("#ItemID").select2({
            minimumInputLength:3,
            ajax: {
                url: 'json/getItemList.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return { 
                        Src: params.term
                    };
                },
             processResults: function (data) {
                    var items = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                        items.push({id: data[i][0], text: data[i][1]});
                    }
                    return {
                        results: items,
                    }
             },                  
            },
        });
```

Related PHP code

```
<?php

$Src            = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['Src']))
    $Src        = $_REQUEST['Src'];

// Write your own code to fetch data, and replace the below line 
//$oList        = $mdb->getItemListJSON3($tcmp->getCompanyID(), $Src, 2);

$jsonStr    =   json_encode($oList);    

print($jsonStr);

?>
```