# How to concatenate results onto a single row? (TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, union

I found the following link: [SQL, How to Concatenate results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339788/sql-how-to-concatenate-results)

However, my use case is slightly different. I have ~64 fields (allowed values `Y` and `N`) that are all called "QryGroup" followed by a number.

I've written a query (Query 1) to create another query (Query 2) that will return all the column names where the QryGroup has at least one value = 'Y' within a defined subset.

However, in order to do this, it's creating a large number of unions in order to  get all of the values together. Query 1 is working correctly to create Query 2 in such a way that Query 2 gives me the result I'm looking for, but all in separate lines. I'd like to concatenate these into a single line so that I can put them into Query 3, to only show the columns where at least one of the records in the subset have a 'Y' value in them.

To give an example, I don't want a table with the following columns:

```
Item Name    Item Description    QryGroup1    QryGroup2    QryGroup3    QryGroup4    QryGroup5    QryGroup6    QryGroup7    QryGroup8
```

when only QryGroup1, 4, and 6 have a non-'N' value. Instead, I want to have

```
Item Name    Item Description    QryGroup1    QryGroup4    QryGroup6
```

I have the following query that, in this case, would return the values

```
`QryGroup1`
`QryGroup4`
`QryGroup6`
```

Query 2:

```
select 'QryGroup1' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup1 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup1 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup2' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup2 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup2 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup3' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup3 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup3 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup4' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup4 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup4 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup5' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup5 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup5 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup6' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup6 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup6 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup7' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup7 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup7 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 
union all
select 'QryGroup8' FROM OITM
WHERE QryGroup8 <> 'N'  AND oitm.itemcode in ([subset])
GROUP BY QryGroup8 HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0
```

I don't think that the link that I posted above will work in my situation because I'm trying to concatenate `Union`ed results, instead of just normal results.

If you need more clarification, please let me know. I've also included the "Query 1" below, if it helps:

```
SELECT  replace(replace(replace(stuff(   (select cast('union all select ''' as nvarchar(max)) 
+ column_name + 
cast(''' FROM OITM' as nvarchar(max))
+ char(13) + 
cast(' WHERE ' as nvarchar(max))
+ column_name + 
cast( ' <> ''N''  AND oitm.itemcode in (subset)' as nvarchar(max))
+char(13) +
cast(' GROUP BY ' as nvarchar(max)) 
+ column_name   +
cast(' HAVING COUNT(*)<> 0 ' as nvarchar(max))  
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_schema = 'dbo'
            and   table_name = 'OITM'
            and   column_name like 'QryGroup%%'
            for xml path(''))
        ,1,10,''), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), '&#x0D;', char(13))
```

Comment: Use your UNION query as a Derived table, and you can treat it the same as a single table in your concatenate query, using the link that you posted.

Comment: Good call! I should have thought of that. Thanks!